# Pushdown automaton for (a^n b^n)^m c^m

Tags: pushdown-automaton

I'm stuck building the transition functions for this automaton.

I suppose I should stack a 1 for each a and unstack it for each b

The number of c's equals the number of ab pairs, so I think I should stack a 0 for each b I encounter. Thing is: how do I unstack 1s and add 0s at the same time?

Comment: Refresh my memory: Do pushdown automata support lamda transitions?

Comment: @Mark Byers: yes, it is.

@Anon.: I don't know! But I'm sure they can be non-deterministic and transition to two different states using the same symbol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't push a `0` onto the stack each time you encounter a `b`. Instead, push a `0` onto the stack each time you encounter a `b` and the stack is empty or the top of the stack is a `0`.

So, using your nomenclature for `aabbabcc`:

```
read a push 1
read a push 1
read b pop 1
read b pop 1
stack is empty so push 0
read a push 1
read b pop 1 
top of stack is 0 so push 0
read c pop 0
read c pop 0
```

Stack is empty so we accept this string.