# Pushdown automaton (a^x b a^y c a^x+y )

Tags: pushdown-automaton

My friend asked me a question about pushdown automaton.  abacaa.    I'm looking at some similar problems but all problems contain even numbers just like 0^a 1^a but now I have 3 values. I've found [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082438/pushdown-automaton-for-an-bnm-cm) about that but i can't convert my question to this.

```
aabbabcc:

read a push 1
read a push 1
read b pop 1
read b pop 1
stack is empty so push 0
read a push 1
read b pop 1 
top of stack is 0 so push 0
read c pop 0
read c pop 0
```

How can i convert  abacaa  ?

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been here a while, but just in case anybody is searching for similar questions... why rehash this?

The basic idea is this: a pushdown automaton has a stack. So, read in as many a's as you want, pushing an extra "a" to the stack each time. Then read b and go to the next state.

Now read as many a's as you want again, pushing all a's onto the stack again. Then read a c and go to the next state.

Now, read a's as long as you are looking at an 'a' on the top of the stack. When you are looking at the bottom-of-the-stack symbol, transition to a final accepting state.

If you have more a's, there are no transitions and your string is not accepted (you're not done reading, and you have nowhere left to go, so you "crash" the machine). Otherwise, if you ran out of a's in the previous state, you never make it to the final state and your string is not accepted. *Only if you just read as many a's as you did the first two times do you end up in the accepting state with no more input to read, and the string is accepted.*